# Integration inequality of double angle identity.

Tags: integration, angle

I am having trouble grasping why the integrals of $2$ sides of a double angle identity are not equal to each other. Given the following identity:

$$\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$$

$$\int \sin(2x)dx = -0.5\cos(2x)$$

$$\int 2\sin(x)\cos(x)dx = -\cos^2(x) \text{ (using u substitution)}$$

plug in $\pi$ for $x$ and it is clear that $-0.5\cos(2x) \ne -\cos^2(x)$

Why is this ?

Comment: Both integrals are "wrong," you left out the $+C$. And both are almost right, they differ by a constant, so when the arbitrary constant of integration is added, they give the same family of functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing the freshman mistake of not including a $+C$ after your integrals. Any function that can be written in the form $-0.5 \cos(2x)+C$ can be written in the form $-\cos^2 (x)+C$, albeit with a different $C$:
$$-{1\over2}\cos(2x) + C = -{1\over2}(2 \cos^2 x - 1) + C = -\cos^2x + {1\over2}+C = -\cos^2x + C'.
$$